# Error messages in NetLogo when trying to use `with`

Tags: netlogo

I'm a new user of NetLogo (5.0.5) and I receive error messages when I try to do pretty basic things. In particular I get

Nothing named x has been defined

when I try to define/use various agentsets. For instance

`show turtles with [color=red]`

`show turtles with [who<10]`

`ask turtles [set friends turtles with [color=red]]`

generate this message (where friends is a turtle variable). However,

`ask turtles [set friends turtles in-radius 7]`

is ok. So it might have to do with 'with'. I'm not sure what do do here. I was following along Jose Vidal's excellent tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5RMdrbJXpM&list=PLSx7bGPy9gbFCWOQ6bAb_4ASLIrblXhqP

and everything was working until i tried

`show cats with [color=red]`

which generated the above error-message. Can anyone help with this?

I haven't found anything about this anywhere but since I'm new there might be resources that do not show up on google (or here) that I've missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some other programming languages, NetLogo doesn't allow you to smash arithmetic and comparison operators up against identifiers; they have to be separated. So you need to write `color = red`, with the spaces, instead of `color=red`, and `who < 10` instead of `who<10`. (If you smash them together, NetLogo thinks the whole thing is a single name for something.)

You can smash brackets `[]` and parentheses `()` up against other things without spaces, but not other punctuation.

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick! Will up-vote as soon as I have 4 more reputation :)